# Fold markers don't display correctly in gvim, but display fine in vim

Tags: vim

I have fold markers in scss marked up like this:

```
/* --- Mixins --- {{{ */
```

And that section, when folded with `fdm=marker` set, renders in vim nicely, like this:

```
+--109 Lines: --- Mixins --- */-----------------------
```

Yet with gvim, I get:

```
+--109 Lines: ----------------------------------------
```

Interestingly, when I put the fold marker before the section name, like `/* --- {{{ Mixins --- */`, gvim behaves as expected.

`:version` reports that I'm using the same version (7.4) of vim and gvim. What could be causing this, and how can I get gvim to behave?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue on my machine (version 7.4). What does `:set fdt?` return for you? For me it is `foldtext=foldtext()`

Comment: Ah, thanks, there it is. On gvim it's `foldtext=PHPFoldText()`, so setting that back to `foldtext=foldtext()` fixed it. This could be a PHP folding plugin that's triggering somehow on gvim but not on vim.

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The text that gets displayed for a closed fold is determined by the foldtext expression `:h 'foldtext'`, `:h fold-foldtext`. The default is to call `foldText()`.

This may be overridden by plugins.

To check what your foldtext expression is use `':set foldtext?'`.